# Некорректный вывод результатов работы программы в файл

Tags: c++, функции

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: имеется код, результаты работы которого, то есть значения функции makswell(u) в цикле, нужно вывести в файл. Однако по какой-то причине в файл записываются одни нули, притом что сама программа делает правильные расчёты. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело. Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
double const Na= 6.02214e+23,Pi=3.14159, k=1.38065e-23;
double M,m,T;


double makswell(int u)
{
 double P;
    P=4*Pi*pow(u, 2)*pow((m/(2*Pi*k*T)), (3/2))*exp(-m*pow(u, 2)/2/k/T);
 std::cout <<  "P=" << P << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
std::ofstream out ("makswell.txt", std::ios::app);
    std::cout << "Введите значения m, T.\n";
    std::cin >> M >> T;
 m=M*0.001/Na;
    int u;
    for (u=0; u<=1000; u+=10)
    out << makswell(u) << std::endl;
 return 0;
 out.close();
}
```

Comment: `return 0;
 out.close();` - это не то чтобы ошибка, фaйл все равно закроется - просто бессмысленно...

Answer (score 2):

Вся ваша проблема (как вы это скомпилировали??!!) в том, что ваша функция `maxwell` **НЕ** возвращает значения...

```
return P;
```

перед закрывающей скобкой функции спасет.

Но все же - как и чем вы ее компилировали, что компилятор не ткнул вас носом в эту ошибку и скомпилировал?..

Comment: gcc под линуксом скомпилировал без warning'а...

Comment: @zcorvid, я было подумал что вы забыли какой-нибудь `-pedantic`, но оказалось что gcc [выдает варнинг](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77dde496f934e5ac) с дефолтными опциями. Зачем вы нас обманывайте?:)

Comment: Хм... видимо действительно обманываю, скорее всего у меня в линуксе по умолчанию gcc какие-то опции имеет. У меня он действительно скомпилился как есть :) . А вот опции там наверное какие-то спрятаны...

Comment: Для данного варнинга нужен -Wall , у меня в системе он походу по умолчанию отключён... По крайней мере на http://cpp.sh/7tpd6 после отключения -Wall больше варнинг не выдаётся.